# Wordpress and SVG - Show column when scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, svg

first thanks for reading my question.

I'm starting a new site, and we are using a WordPress theme and his builder (Divi Theme). The main feature is some SVG's vectors, which takes about 3 seconds to complete. Here start my problem. When the user opens the page, all the SVG's images start to load, and the user can't see the animation progress. There's a way to make the image only show by scroll position? I mean, the image appears and start the animation only when the user is on the viewpoint of the image. I've found some CSS and JS codes here, but I can't make this work.

Comment: Sure, you could get more content via Ajax and append it to the existing content.

Comment: Did you try waypoints? http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/